# Activate ip rule in kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ip

I'm a beginner in network and linux fields and I need to work with policy routing but first I need to activate ip rule in the kernel.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and minicon 2.7

when I run ip rule show nothing happens, but I guess it needs to display something like this :

```
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

isn't?

Is there some tokens that needs to be activated in the CONFIG file?

Comment: Nothing happens as in 'command not found', or is there no output?

Comment: nothing happens, it seems like I had to activate some kernel CONFIGS
I added them and it's working now

Comment: So you recompiled the kernel? Because I'd be surprised a stock Ubuntu kernel didn't provide it already.

Comment: Yes just checked, [16.04.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic/download)'s kernel has CONFIG_IP(V6)?_MULTIPLE_TABLES

Comment: yes, I found my answer here https://superuser.com/questions/232807/iproute2-not-functioning-rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-supported